# Subtotal minimum amount

Tags: cognito-forms

I have an order form where the minimum order, before shipping, needs to be $150.00

How do I create the formula for this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

You can set this up using a [Calculation field](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/2/calculations) with the title of 'Subtotal' and the following calculation to call and see what the Subtotal of the form is, you will also want to set the fields 'Type' to 'Currency'.

```
=Order.SubTotal
```

You can then set up a custom error that will prevent a user form submitting the form when the Subtotal is less then $150.00. In the custom error message, the field that i'm checking is the 'Subtotal' calculation field.

[image]